# SignalR with asp.net core clean architecture and flutter is not working on live server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

SignalR with asp.net 3.1 and flutter app is working fine with local server but its not working on live server.
I/flutter (28526): HubConnection connected successfully. I/flutter (28526): BTJiJtOdpGPjUyvYAzb4sA I/flutter (28526): Connection state 'HubConnectionState.connected' I/flutter (28526): notification received from server I/flutter (28526): (SSE transport) sending data. String data of length '11'. I/flutter (28526): (SSE transport) request complete. Response status: 404.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSignalR(e =>
    {
        e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
        e.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        e.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        e.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
         endpoints.MapHub<ChatHubs>("/chathub");
     });
```

**At flutter side with signalr_core: ^1.1.1**

```
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(ApisUrls.baseUrl+"/chathub", HttpConnectionOptions(
       accessTokenFactory: () async => await headerHelper.gettokenWithoutBearer(),
      logging:(level, message) => print(message),
    )
    ).withAutomaticReconnect().build();

   // hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 60000;
    if (hubConnection.state != HubConnectionState.connected) {
      await hubConnection.start();
      print('${hubConnection.connectionId}');
      setState(() {

      });
    }

    // When the connection is closed, print out a message to the console.
    hubConnection.onclose( (error) => print("Connection Closed"));

    hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", _handleAClientProvidedFunction);
    hubConnection.on("OnConnectedAsync", _onConnectFunction);
    hubConnection.on("OnDisConnectedAsync", _onDisConnectFunction);

class ApisUrls {

  // static final baseUrl = "http://localhost:57712"; // local api// local api
  static final baseUrl = "http://185.249.225.188:5005";
}
```